# VS Code Debug Dynamically Inserted JS with mapping file

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-debugger, map-files

I have a typescript project in VS code (obviously running on Node and using Debugger for Chrome extension).  My html file references a static javascript file, but then that javascript file dynamically injects the contents of a javascript resource.

```
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute("rbl-script", "true");
script.innerHTML = content;
body.appendChild(script);
```

In the code above, `content` is the return data from a call using `$.ajax( ajaxConfig )` with `ajaxConfig.url` set to 'http://localhost:8887/js/KatAppProvider.js' and that is the generated javascript file from `tsc --build`.  (Note, I can't just statically link this file, because in production, the `$.ajax` request is going to a content management web service.)

If I try to set breakpoints in VS Code in the corresponding *KatAppProvider.ts* file, they are never hit.  The problem seems to be the `//# sourceMappingURL=KatAppProvider.js.map` generated line.  I think everything used to work fine and possibly a VS Code or extension update changed the behavior, but I can't confirm.  The only way I can get this to work, is to manually modify that mapping url line in the generated file after building to `//# sourceMappingURL=js/KatAppProvider.js.map` (to include the *js/*).

1. Am I remembering wrong in my thinking that this worked as is (without the *js/* prefix)?
2. Is this the expected behavior with my scenario?  And if so, is there a way to change *only* this files compilation to include the *js/* prefix (but no other files - i.e. the statically linked ones in the project)